mvn clean install to skip integration test
I want mvn clean install to skip integration tests and I am using surefire to run unit tests and failsafe to run integration tests. Folder structure for reference, mvn clean install should skip ApplicationIT test and any other test ending with IT.
POM.xml
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>



First the exclusion of *IT.java in Maven Surefire Plugin is superfluous because It's default. The next point: Why running mvn install? Use mvn verify to run unit- and integration tests and run mvn test to run only unit tests... Also I recommend to have the same version for maven-surefire/failsafe-plugin...

Because verify runs before install in the Maven lifecycle, when you execute mvn install it will automatically run your integration tests because they run during the verify phase.  If you want to run the install without running the integration tests, pass the skipITs argument to your command.  mvn install -DskipITs
